# Vaikunta Ekadashi and Swarga door opening significance

Tags: vishnu, ekadashi

Vaikuntha Ekadashi is known as Mukkoti Ekadashi. This Ekadashi is popularly celebrated in South India. Ekadashi is purely dedicated to worship Lord Shri Hari Vishnu.
As per Tamil Calendar, Vaikunth Ekadashi is going to be observed on 11th day of Shukla Paksha in the month of Margazhi.

Vaikunth Ekadashi is popularly celebrated in the southern states. Srirangam and Tirupati Temple celebrations are primarily known for the Vaikuntha Ekadashi. Vishnu temples have rituals called Swarga door opening where symbolic door of Swarga opened in the morning.

**What is the significance of Vaikunta Ekadasi and the ritual of Swarga door opening on the day?**

Shine internet sources say churning of ocean (Sagar Mathana) was performed on this sacred day of Vaikunth Ekadashi. But looking for references from scriptures.

Comment: The significance of Vaikuṇṭha Ekādaśī, concerning with the opening of Swarga door, find it's mention in Pāñcarātra agama of Śrī Praśnasaṃhitā. The 46th adhyāya of the text narrates the story.